# MOSS 2007 and Sql Server Reporting Services from dev to prod

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

When building a MOSS site in a development environment and incorporating Sql Server Reporting Service (SSRS) web parts how would I then go about moving these to a production environment?

Would I need to duplicate the work to configure SSRS and then move these any pages/web parts that are referencing the SSRS?

Would appreciate anyones thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring SSRS in Sharepoint integrated mode, especially within a farm is far from trivial.  Thus this will all need to be re-configured.  Are you sharing the SSRS server between dev and prod?

Providing SSRS is all working on the Production machines I assume you can then move the pages as you would any other sharepoint page.  Do bear in mind that the .RDL files are content within the document libraries.  If you use integrated authentication on your data sources (.rds) then I would expect these will move as well, if however you are using SQL Authentication I doubt they will move due to the way the passwords are encrypted.

Comment: Cheers Joel. The dev is a completely seperate virtual dev environment solely for my use - then in-house they have a prod environment. So I'll have repeat the work to configure their setup for integration with SSRS  and then move pages from dev accordingly? I just wondered if there's a best practice approach to this :) Just trying to do things the right way!